# Build Microsoft.AspNet.Identity from source, throws error when resolving packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to build AspNetIdentity from source available in https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity. It throws errors in the build process. Steps to reproduce:

1. Start Visual Studio 2019 Community and select `Clone a repository`. Enter the following URL and click `Clone`:
   https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity.git
2. Copy nuget.exe to the `.nuget` directory in the cloned project.
3. Build the solution.

The output is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>------ Build started: Project: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  Restoring NuGet packages...
2>  To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the NuGet Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.
2>  Feeds used:
2>    C:\Users\MyUserName\.nuget\packages\
2>    http://myget.org/F/owin
2>    https://nuget.org/api/v2/
2>  
2>  Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1.
2>  Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.3.0.1.
2>  Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Owin.Security.3.0.1.
2>  Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.3.0.1.
2>  Adding package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.3.0.1' to folder 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages'
2>  Adding package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.3.0.1' to folder 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages'
2>  Adding package 'Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1' to folder 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages'
2>  Adding package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.3.0.1' to folder 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages'
2>EXEC : warning : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.3.0.1'.
2>EXEC : warning : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.3.0.1'.
2>EXEC : warning : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1'.
2>EXEC : warning : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.3.0.1'.
2>  Restoring NuGet package Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4.
2>  Restoring NuGet package Owin.1.0.0.
2>  Adding package 'Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4' to folder 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages'
2>  Adding package 'Owin.1.0.0' to folder 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages'
2>EXEC : warning : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Owin.1.0'.
2>EXEC : warning : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4'.
2>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.3.0.1'.
2>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.3.0.1'.
2>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.3.0.1'.
2>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1'.
2>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Owin.1.0'.
2>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4'.
2>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.exe" install "C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\src\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin\packages.config" -source "http://myget.org/F/owin;https://nuget.org/api/v2/"  -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ "" exited with code 1.
1>  Restoring NuGet packages...
1>  To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the NuGet Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.
1>  Feeds used:
1>    C:\Users\MyUserName\.nuget\packages\
1>    http://myget.org/F/owin
1>    https://nuget.org/api/v2/
1>  
1>  Restoring NuGet package EntityFramework.6.1.1.
1>  Adding package 'EntityFramework.6.1.1' to folder 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages'
1>EXEC : warning : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1'.
1>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1'.
1>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.exe" install "C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\src\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework\packages.config" -source "http://myget.org/F/owin;https://nuget.org/api/v2/"  -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ "" exited with code 1.
3>------ Build started: Project: Identity.Test, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
3>  Restoring NuGet packages...
3>  To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the NuGet Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.
3>  Feeds used:
3>    C:\Users\MyUserName\.nuget\packages\
3>    http://myget.org/F/owin
3>    https://nuget.org/api/v2/
3>  
3>  Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.3.0.1.
3>  Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Owin.Security.3.0.1.
3>  Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1.
3>  Restoring NuGet package EntityFramework.6.1.1.
3>  Adding package 'Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1' to folder 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages'
3>  Adding package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.3.0.1' to folder 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages'
3>  Adding package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.3.0.1' to folder 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages'
3>  Adding package 'EntityFramework.6.1.1' to folder 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages'
3>EXEC : warning : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.3.0.1'.
3>EXEC : warning : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1'.
3>EXEC : warning : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.3.0.1'.
3>EXEC : warning : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1'.
3>  Restoring NuGet package Moq.4.0.10827.
3>  Restoring NuGet package Owin.1.0.0.
3>  Restoring NuGet package xunit.extensions.1.9.2.
3>  Restoring NuGet package xunit.1.9.2.
3>  Adding package 'Owin.1.0.0' to folder 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages'
3>  Adding package 'Moq.4.0.10827' to folder 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages'
3>  Adding package 'xunit.extensions.1.9.2' to folder 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages'
3>  Adding package 'xunit.1.9.2' to folder 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages'
3>EXEC : warning : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Owin.1.0'.
3>EXEC : warning : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\xunit.extensions.1.9.2'.
3>EXEC : warning : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\xunit.1.9.2'.
3>EXEC : warning : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Moq.4.0.10827'.
3>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.3.0.1'.
3>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1'.
3>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1'.
3>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.3.0.1'.
3>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Owin.1.0'.
3>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\xunit.extensions.1.9.2'.
3>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\xunit.1.9.2'.
3>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Moq.4.0.10827'.
3>C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\.nuget\nuget.exe" install "C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\test\Identity.Test\packages.config" -source "http://myget.org/F/owin;https://nuget.org/api/v2/"  -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ "" exited with code 1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 3 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It seems there is a problem with the following directory paths which contain the `\ \` part, but I don't know why is it included in the path:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\Source\Repos\AspNetIdentity\ \packages\Moq.4.0.10827
```

Comment: The issue is from `RestoreCommand` of the `nuget.targets` file. And by default, `solutiondir` property contains \. And in the command, it will make the MSBuild unable to find the package address. So you should remove that \.

Comment: I will add an answer to help you resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Build Microsoft.AspNet.Identity from source, throws error when
> resolving packages

The issue is under `RestoreCommand` of the `nuget.targets` file.

**And** by default, `SolutionDir` property contains `\`. And in the command, it will make the **MSBuild** unable to find the package address.

**Besides**, I noticed that:

`-solutionDir "$(SolutionDir) "</RestoreCommand>`

there is a space between `SolutionDir` and `"`, you should delete it.

**Solution**

change to use this in `nuget.targets` file:

```
<SolutionDir1>$(SolutionDir.Trim('\'))</SolutionDir1>

<RestoreCommand>$(NuGetCommand) install "$(PackagesConfig)" -source "$(PackageSources)"  $(RequireConsentSwitch) -solutionDir "$(SolutionDir1)"</RestoreCommand>
```

**When you finish it**, **you should close VS and then restart your project** to reload the new csproj file to enable your changes.

**Notice**: use a new property `SolutionDir1` which removes that `\` and then use it in the command.